# OSN 2018, Part 8

Tags: probability

> There is a coin that is unbalanced in a way so that the probability of outputting a digit is $\frac{1}{4}$. If it is tossed $n$ times, the probability that there will be exactly $2$ digits is equal to the probability that there will be exactly $3$ digits. The value of $n$ is...

The following is a solution that I found from a book, it's elegant to me but there's just one part that I don't get:

First let $P(A)$ be the probability of outputting a digit, then $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Similarly, let $P(G)$ be the probability of outputting a figure (the side opposite of the digit), then $P(G)=1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Now here is the confusing part:

Then if the coin is tossed $n$ times, the probability landing $2$ digits and therefore $n-2$ figures is $\binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-2}$.

Similarly with $3$ digits (and $n-3$ figures) is $\binom{n}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-3}$.

Then to find the value of $n$ is to just make the two probability equal and solve for $n$.

My question is how is the probability $\binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-2}$and $\binom{n}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-3}?$ what is the derivation?

Comment: If you're just browsing, this is the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). If you're actively studying basic probability, you might need to go back and review some earlier material. ¶ Also, is this translated from something else? "Digit" is a weird word to use there; it refers to any of $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$. Normally, we would expect to see either "heads" or "tails" there.

Comment: @BrianTung Ah, I'm new to probability so thanks for the heads-up! I'll be looking into that.

And yes this was translated from a competition problem from 6 years ago in Indonesia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this a community wiki answer.

As OP indicated, this problem is translated from a different language, with attendant issues. (The [OSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia_National_Science_Olympiad) is the Indonesian National Science Olympiad.) We'll assume the question is something along the lines of:

> We have a biased coin with probability $p = 1/4$ of flipping heads. If such a coin is flipped a certain number $n$ times, it turns out that it has an equal probability of coming up heads two times and coming up heads three times. What is $n$?

We apply the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), according to which the probabilities of flipping two heads and of flipping three heads are

$$
P(k = 2) = \binom{n}{2}\left(\frac14\right)^2\left(\frac34\right)^{n-2}
$$
$$
P(k = 3) = \binom{n}{3}\left(\frac14\right)^3\left(\frac34\right)^{n-3}
$$

where the binomial coefficient is in general

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

Expanding these and dividing out common factors yields

$$
\frac{n-2}{3} = 3
$$

or $n = 11$.